# Strange behaviour for echo with -e flag passed to bash with -c flag

Tags: bash

I cannot understand the behaviour of this bash script (which I cut it out of a longer real use case):

```
# This is test.sh
cmd="echo -e \"\n\n\n\t===== Hello World =====\n\n\""
sh -c "$cmd"
```

What it prints is:

```
$ ./test.sh
-e


    ===== Hello World =====
$
```

If I remove the -e flag, everything is printed correctly, with quoted chars correctly interpreted and without the '-e' spoil: but it shouldn't be like that.

My bash is: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)`, under macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Posix mode (when run as `sh`), `bash` 3.2's `echo` command takes no options; `-e` is just another argument to write to standard output. Compare:

```
$ bash -c 'echo -e "a\tb"'
a   b
$ sh -c 'echo -e "a\tb"'
-e a    b
```

A literal tab is printed in both cases because Posix `echo` behaves the same as `bash` `echo -e`.

For this reason, `printf` is almost always better to use than `echo` to provide consistent behavior.

```
cmd='printf "\n\n\n\t===== Hello World =====\n\n"'
sh -c "$cmd"
```

Comment: Thanks, chepner, we posted our answers simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

sh-4.2# cat test.sh
cmd="echo -e \"\n\n\n\t===== Hello World =====\n\n\""
sh -c "$cmd"

sh-4.2# ./test.sh

```
===== Hello World =====
```

sh-4.2#

It is getting printed correctly on my machine

Comment: `bash` 3.2 and `bash` 4.2 behave differently in this regard when invoked as `sh`.

Comment: OK, it's bash version, just tried on the target server having 4.1. But, what is it exaclty?

Comment: See my answer; all versions of `bash` behave differently when invoked as `sh`, and in the case of version 3.2, one of those differences involves the interpretation of the non-POSIX optional argument `-e`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found it myself, from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/517895/190592):

*sh, the Bourne shell, is old. Its behaviour is specified by the POSIX standard. If you want new behaviour, you use bash, the Bourne Again shell, which gets new features added to it all the time. On many systems, sh is just bash, and bash turns on a compatibility mode when run under that name.*

Groan...