# Use echo options when execution shell script

Tags: bash, macos, echo

On mac OSX, I have this script:

```sh
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
echo -e "\e[41mError: Some error.\e[0m"
```

When I just run the `echo -e ...` in a console, it prints the colored text "Error: Some error."

When executed as a script `sh myscript.sh`, it litterally prints the flag and the escape characters: `-e "\e[41mError: Some error.\e[0m"`.

When I add the script location to `~/.bash_profile` and execute it as `myscript.sh`, it does work. But I need to be able execute it without adding it to my bash profile.

Edit: using printf works: `printf "\e[41mError: Some error.\e[0m\n"`.

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/bash` exists?

Comment: But why use `sh` if you want to run with with bash

Comment: It seems that bash dir it's not there anymore. But you're right. When adjusting the path to `#!/bin/bash` or removing that line, it still won't work.

Comment: Not sure where you'd find that escape sequence, but use `#!/bin/bash` as shebang, then use `echo -e '\033[0;31mError: Some Error.\033[0m'` and call it with `./script.sh`

Comment: Side note: if adding colour and other terminal control sequences to a shell script, it's good practise to only do it if the output file descriptor actually refers to a terminal. This allows the sequences to be excluded when piping to a filter, or capturing to a file. You can test if output is to a terminal: `test -t 2` for stderr. I like to implement this by using variables for the control sequences (like `red_2='\e[41m'`), and then only set them if the test returns true for that fd.

Comment: Different versions of `echo` behave differently when parsing options and/or escape sequences; I had a bunch of my scripts break when Mac OS X 10.5 (I think that was the version) came out and its bash built-in changed behavior(!). `printf` is more complex to use properly (its first argument is a format string that's used to control how the rest of the arguments are printed), but it's way more predictable. For this, I'd use `printf '\e[41m%s\e[0m' "Error: Some error."`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101308) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712644).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you run the shell with `sh` it runs in posix compatibility mode (i.e. as the bourne shell does)

bash is a successor to this shell, one of the features it adds is the -e switch to echo

in posix shell you don't need the -e, the escapes will be evaluated anyway

in bash you do, so if you want to run bash do so explicitly