# How to catch special keys in Bash

Tags: bash, special-characters

I want a program that catch just one special keys like `Enter`, `Tab`, `UP_ARROW`, `DOWN_ARROW`, etc and just one `NORMAL` characters (A-Z, 0-9, !-?).

what i tried is:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -rsn2 Input
read -rsn1 Input

if [[ $Input == "A" ]]; then
    echo "Up"
elif [[ $Input == "B" ]]; then 
    echo "Down"
fi
```

But here I'm unable to catch one `NORMAL` characters(a-z, 0-9), Infact I always have to enter 3 characters to get Output.
Also I'm unable to differentiate between `ENTER` and `SPACE` keys.

Any suggestions or advice is very helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Cursor movements are sequences of several characters (usually). Check [infocmp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/infocmp)

Comment: You can't catch "keys" in this way. You are reading from standard input: This is a stream of characters in your characters set (ASCII, UTF8, whatever you choose). A "key" is not a character. What you need, is to get a _keycode_ (i.e. a code identifying which key has been pressed). This is of course dependent on your operating system. I suggest that you google for _get keycode on Linux_ (or whatever OS you are using).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
while true; do
read -rs -N 1 Event1
case "$Event1" in
    [[:graph:]])    Event="$Event1" ;;
    $'\n')          Event="ENTER"   ;;
    ' ')            Event="SPACE"   ;;
    [[:blank:]])    Event="TAB"     ;; # TAB must remain below SPACE and ENTER
    *)
        read -t 0.01 -rsn5 Event2
        case "$Event2" in
        
            "[A")       Event="UP"          ;;
            "[B")       Event="DOWN"        ;;
            "[D")       Event="LEFT"        ;;
            "[C")       Event="RIGHT"       ;;

            "[P"|"[3~")     Event="DEL"         ;;
            "[4h"|"[2~")    Event="INS"         ;;
            "[4~"|"[F")     Event="END"         ;;
            "[H"|"[1~")     Event="HOM"         ;;
            "[5~")          Event="PGUP"        ;;
            "[6~")          Event="PGDO"        ;;

            "OP"|"[[A")     Event="F1"          ;;
            "OQ"|"[[B")     Event="F2"          ;;
            "OR"|"[[C")     Event="F3"          ;;
            "OS"|"[[D")     Event="F4"          ;;
            "[15~"|"[[E")   Event="F5"          ;;
            "[17~")         Event="F6"          ;;
            "[18~")         Event="F7"          ;;
            "[19~")         Event="F8"          ;;
            "[20~")         Event="F9"          ;;
            "[21~")         Event="F10"         ;;
            "[23~")         Event="F11"         ;;
            "[24~")         Event="F12"         ;;
            
            *)
                case "$Event1$Event2" in 
                    $'\E')      Event="ESC"     ;;
                    $'\177'|*)  Event="BCKSPC"  ;; # Remaining keys will be treated as Backspace
                esac
                ;;
        esac
esac
printf "${Event} \n"
done
```

and can also be done same with Combination keys like `CTRL+A` and `ALT+1`.

*Tested on: Xterm, st-terminal, alacritty, xfce4-terminal and default tty*

Comment: It may be helpful to explain arrow-keys are multi-byte keys that you are handling by matching in a `case` statement against the escapes `'[..'` where `..` are any of the characters listed.  Also See [Strange behaviour for echo with -e flag passed to bash with -c flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51101308/3422102), [Escape sequences with echo -e in different shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88307/197080), and [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/197080).

Comment: Worthy of the nod for the correct answer though...

Comment: Also note this is highly terminal/mapping dependent. For example, xterm on some distros use `"[F"` for `END` and `"[2~"` for `INS` and `"[3~"` for `DEL`.

Comment: There is no need to assign `Event=$Event`, that should read `[[:graph:]]) ;;`