# Can't print with colors by using environment variables

Tags: c, bash

I have a .echo_colors file containing some variables for colors in the following format:

```
export red="\033[0;31m"
```

this works fine with echo -e, but i want to use this environment variables on a C code. I'm getting the variable via getenv and printing with printf:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char* color = getenv("red");
    printf("%s", color);
    printf("THIS SHOULD BE IN RED\n");
    return 0;
}
```

with this program, i get

```
\033[0;31mTHIS SHOULD BE IN RED
```

The string is just being printed and not interpreted as a color code. **printf("\033[0;31m")** works and prints output in red as i want to. Any ideas for what to do to correct this problem?

Comment: Why not simply create a header file, say `ansicolor.h` and within it (properly guarded) `#define RED "\033[0;31m"` (and the rest) and `#define NC  "\033[0m"` (for no color) to return to normal? Then rather than querying the environment and worrying about shell syntax, you simply include the C header??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't interpret `\033` as "ESC" by default, as evident from hex-dumping the variable, but as "backslash, zero, three, three":

```
bash-3.2$ export red="\033[0;31m"
bash-3.2$ echo $red | xxd
00000000: 5c30 3333 5b30 3b33 316d 0a              \033[0;31m.
```

You'll need to use [a different Bash syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11966402/51685) to export the variable to have *it* interpret the escape sequence (instead of `echo -e` doing it):

```
export red=$'\033[0;31m'
```

i.e.

```
bash-3.2$ export red=$'\033[0;31m'
bash-3.2$ echo $red | xxd
00000000: 1b5b 303b 3331 6d0a                      .[0;31m.
```

Comment: This works. I thought the problem was probably bash syntax but still didnt't know how to fix this. Thank you very much

Comment: Also, avoid using `echo -e` if at all possible --`echo` options are a hopelessly inconsistent mess. See ["Strange behaviour for `echo` with `-e` flag passed to bash with `-c` flag"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101308/strange-behaviour-for-echo-with-e-flag-passed-to-bash-with-c-flag), ["Escape sequences with `echo -e` in different shells"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88307/escape-sequences-with-echo-e-in-different-shells), and ["Why is `printf` better than `echo`?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

Answer (score 0):

Use `^[`  (Control-left-bracket) in your shell script to key in the `export command`, as in

```
$ export red="<ctrl-[>[0;31m"
```

in your shell script, the `ctrl-[` is actually the escape character (as typed from the terminal, it is possible that you need to escape it with Ctrl-V so it is not interpreted as an editing character, in that case, put a Ctrl-V in front of the escape char)

If you do

```
$ echo "<ctrl-[>[31mTHIS SHOULD BE IN RED"
THIS SHOULD BE IN RED                   (in red letters)
$ _
```

you will see the effect.